# What is the best way to display fonts in OpenGL?

Tags: performance, opengl, fonts, glsl, transparency

In OpenGL, many ways to draw text on screen are possible. I want to choose the best and mainly the most efficient way. As far as I know, you can use e.g. one of these:

1. **Bitmap texture:**

   ```
   BMPbase = glGenLists(256);
   for(int loop = 0; loop < 256; loop++)
   {
   cx = float(loop % 16) / 16.0f;
   cy = float(loop / 16) / 16.0f;

   glNewList(BMPbase + loop, GL_COMPILE);
   glBegin(GL_QUADS);
   glTexCoord2f(cx, 1 - cy);                       glVertex2i(0, 0);
   glTexCoord2f(cx + 0.0625f, 1 - cy);             glVertex2i(Size, 0);
   glTexCoord2f(cx + 0.0625f, 1 - cy - 0.0625f);   glVertex2i(Size, Size);
   glTexCoord2f(cx, 1 - cy - 0.0625f);             glVertex2i(0, Size);
   glEnd();

   glTranslated(10, 0, 0);
   glEndList();
   }
   ```
2. **FreeType fonts:**

   ```
   glPushAttrib(GL_LIST_BIT);
   glListBase(base - 32);
   glCallLists(strlen(text), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, text);
   glPopAttrib();
   ```
3. **Outline fonts:**

   ```
   Font = CreateFont(12,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   FW_BOLD,
   FALSE,
   FALSE,
   FALSE,
   ANSI_CHARSET,
   OUT_TT_PRECIS,
   CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,
   ANTIALIASED_QUALITY,
   FF_DONTCARE|DEFAULT_PITCH,
   "Times New Roman");

   wglUseFontOutlines(hdc,
   0,
   255,
   base,
   0.0f,
   0.5f,
   WGL_FONT_POLYGONS,
   GMF);
   ```

Currently I'm using the bitmap fonts, but the problem is, that the more text I draw, the less FPS I have. It is really significant if I draw one line of 10 characters or 5 lines of 10 characters.

Which are the best font techniques for performance and quality?
I know, that I can somehow draw font using shaders, which seems like the best and most efficient solution, since the fonts would be stored in GPU memory, but I have no idea, how could I draw fonts using (GLSL) shaders.

Or is there some better way?

Comment: Maybe using functional(instead of bitmap) letter generation, you can use less local memory using shaders. If planets are generated, why not letters?

Comment: Thanks for a quick response! That will not solve the low FPS problem, right? I want to be able to draw a lot of text with really low fps impact.

Comment: With opencl, i was drawing with only a single core of gpu, it was rendering hundreds to thousands of characters per second easily but using simple line functions. Here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r9gcCMl_eMc the green digited number.

Comment: Sounds good, but does not look :D I want something like this: http://i.imgur.com/JvCCYrf.jpg (this is what I have using bitmap fonts)

Comment: Maybe bezier curves can do that and has immunity to resolution changes.

Comment: I have done some drawing of bezier curves, but they are not that easy from my point of view. At least the bezier curves I have on my mind. I can't imagine getting data from some ttf files, making bezier curves from them and then draw them. If you know about some easy way to draw bezier lines based fonts, it would be great!

Comment: No I dont know that. Are you assembling those bitmaps in a single buffer and keeping it on the gpu memory? Or is the pci-e overhead?

Comment: The bitmap itself I am loading from resource and the font is stored in display list.

Comment: I'm working on a gui, and for now I choosed to build texture atlas with chars and render text using vao's. The final text could be rendered with a fbo and then you may only display a quad with the whole text (or at least cache some paragraph) exemple (mine is not yet commited): http://code.google.com/p/freetype-gl/

Comment: That's very similar to what I am doing with the display list, isn't it?

Comment: Oh, I missed the part where you load the ttf files instead of loading bitmap with characters...It looks cool!